# Is there a shortcut to Investigate or Enter Orbit when cruising around a system?

Tags: pc, mass-effect-3

I haven't been able to locate a PC short cut to investigate or enter orbit when scanning a sector.  This would be very helpful as I'm often being chased by Reapers who want to ... well ... reap me.

Getting into orbit of the fuel pod or planetoid as quickly as possible helps cut down on all the reaping going on.

Does anyone know this shortcut?

Comment: Can't you just press the button that shows up when you're close enough to investigate/enter orbit? Should be the "run" button, at least it is on PS3.

Comment: At my resolution it's often a fair distance from my mouse pointer which is sometimes frantically directing my Normandy ... especially if the depot/planet is near the edge of the system or very near the center of the map.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you double click on the object (planet, depot, jump) it will activate the "Investigate" (or whatever) control allowing you to substantially increase your ability to get there before the Reapers get you.

I discovered this tonight by accident and thought it was worth sharing.